# Anyone know if you can add text to Hlines or Horizontal line plots via pine script?

Tags: pine-script

Anyone know if you can add text to Hlines or Horizontal line plots via pine script?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done through those functions, but you could use labels to position text near the plots. This is an example of a script doing that. The lines and the text are plotted separately:

https://www.tradingview.com/script/VYzEUnYB-Pivots-MTF-LucF/

[image]